# Java equivalent for a MongoDB select query

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to retrieve the following information:

```
select names from database where names like 'Jon';
```

but for MongoDB in Java. Essentially, it should return all names that contain the word Jon in them, like Jonathan, Jong etc etc. I know that there is the `$in` operator in MongoDB, but how do I do the same in Java, using the Java driver? I've been trying to look for it everywhere but am getting nothing. I've tried: `query = new BasicDBObject("names", new BasicDBObject("$in", "Jon"));`, and `query = new BasicDBObject("names", new BasicDBObject("$in", Jon));`

But neither of them worked :( Please help!

Comment: It would help if you posted some code that you have tried.

Comment: @dadu: I did, but there's nothing for my specific query. I tried `query = new BasicDBObject("names", new BasicDBObject("$in", "Jon"));`, and `query = new BasicDBObject("names", new BasicDBObject("$in", Jon));` But neither of them worked :( I did look up Morphia too, but I'm kinda crunching on time, and implementing that is kinda beyond my time frame, especially since I only need one single query.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals: Please refer my comment now. I realised I hadn't posted my code.

Comment: That SQL query won't do what you say it does. To get everything where the name includes the string "Jon", you would use `LIKE "%Jon%"`. To get only those which start with Jon, you would use `LIKE "Jon%"`. The MongoDB `$in` operator is for searching in array fields. To search for string fragments, you can use `$regex` and regular expressions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MongoDB Java driver equivalent of that SELECT statement would be:

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject().append("name", 1); // SELECT name
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject().append("name", "Jon"); // WHERE name = "Jon"
DBCursor results = yourCollection.find(query, fields); // FROM yourCollection
```

When you want to search for a part of a string, you can use the `$regex` operator:

```
query = new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "Jon"));
```

This will get you all objects where the name matches the [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) `Jon`, which is everything which includes the string "Jon" anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, my query was more like pseudocode, rather than actual code :P Can you please edit your answer accordingly? Thanks! :)

Comment: I edited my answer and added the equivalent to a `LIKE "%Jon%"` query.

Comment: Please look at my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732735/query-in-a-map-reduce-function and please see if you can lend your expertise in any way. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the Mongo-Java [official site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial), plus a nice [library](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) for mapping mongo objects

Answer (score 0):

The `$in` operator in MongoDB resembles the `IN` operator in SQL. For instance, it can be used for executing SQL-like queries as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN {1, 4, 6, 7, 9}
```

This is why it doesn't work for you. Use Regular expressions, as the others have already suggested.